# Who (which process) is calling curl?

Tags: tools, macos

On my mac (Lion), I know that `curl` is bing used by some unknown process to communicate with a server.

Basically I installed little Snitch and find out that "somebody" is using `curl` periodically.
How can I find out who (what process) is firing up these `curl` calls?
I guess if a process is directly calling `curl` I should be able to find who it is (if it is still around by the time I look for it) by checking the process tree (parent to `curl`).

Are there any best practices or specialized utilities to help with this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/curl /usr/bin/curl.bin
sudo vim /usr/bin/curl.wrapper
```

here is the wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh

date >> /var/tmp/curl_ppid.log
ps -f -p $PPID >> /var/tmp/curl_ppid.log

exec curl.bin "$@"
```

and then:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/curl.wrapper
sudo touch /var/tmp/curl_ppid.log
sudo chmod a+w /var/tmp/curl_ppid.log
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/curl.wrapper /usr/bin/curl
```

It is better to keep the wrapper script in another location called `curl.wrapper`, so your package manager will not overwrite your script during an update.

Comment: Fantastic, it was `prey` http://preyproject.com ! I didn't know it keeps checking my connectivity by curling google.com . Phew!

Comment: I cannot do this - attempting the first line results in "Operation not Permitted"

Answer (score 5):

Replace the curl binary with a script to capture the process details.

Answer (score 0):

Because MacOS is Unix-based, "lsof" command will work.

Try:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "curl"
```

or just

```
lsof -i
```

Comment: Really? `lsof -i` should show `curl` itself but not the parent process (the one calling curl).

Comment: Sorry, I'm so used to having to interpret poor grammar on this site that I actually interpreted your proper grammar incorrectly. I thought you were looking for a user who is calling a process ... Feel free to disregard.